# Enterprise Architect - Transfering project from file to PostgreSQL repository

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-architect

I am trying to transfer project file to DB repository (PostgreSQL). During project transfer (copying project information to t_object) error is displayed:

[Error during project transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNrEn.png)

I've repeated it 3 times, every time with the same result. Logfile looks like below:

```
2017-11-13 16:30:20  Copying project information for: t_glossary
2017-11-13 16:30:20  Copying project information for: t_implement
2017-11-13 16:30:20  Copying project information for: t_object
  ERROR: *** t_object - record no: 1345 Key: object_id=3390
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run a Project Consistency Check beforehand. If that does not help you might be forced to use XMI for the model and separately ex-/import for the Reference Data.

Comment: Yes, it helped. I performed project integrity check and then transfer went smoothly. Thanks!